# Storing array of objects inside Redis and retrieving it

Tags: php, arrays, object, redis, predis

We are using PHP, Redis, and Predis. We are trying to store an array of objects in Redis and then retrieve it. We notice arrays cannot be naturally be stored in Redis. What is the best way to store the array of objects and retrieve it later? Here is our array of objects:

```
"data": [
    {
      "doctor_id": 4, -- Use this id for getting in method get inquiry doctor offers.
      "clinic": "John",
      "distance": "10 mile"
      "city": "Los Angeles",
      "photo": "http://localhost/botox/storage/web/source/1/j4DnpszEy7epcUMf_N8QY0SRhbs7vLRG.png",
      "photos": {
         "http://path/image.jpg",
         "http://path/image.jpg1"
      }

      "price": "123",
      "photo": false,
      "rating": {
        "stars": null,
        "reviews": null
      },
      "add_info"=> "Some information",
      "time_after_create": 942 -- in seconds.
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dataJSon = json_encode( $data );
```

Then save $dataJSon as a varchar in your database.

When you retrieve it, use the format:

```
$data = json_decode( $var_name, TRUE ); // TRUE is needed to return to associative array
```

To "echo" an array, either echo each array element or use print_r on the array

Comment: We have already tried json_encode and then stored it in our database. when we are retrieving it, we used json_decode and it does not echo out anything when we retrieve and echo it.

Comment: @baileyJchoi I've updated my answer based upon your comment.

Comment: We have done exactly what you have said but it still does not work. it works with regular strings but it does not print out anything.

Comment: Edit: okay it is working now but very inconsistent. We have to refresh the page multiple times in order for the array to show but most of the time, it does not show.

Comment: @baileyJchoi Something is going wrong with the retrieval from the database. Please show your query code.

Comment: We found the problem. we have two functions. both have `$redis = new Predis\Client();`. that is the problem. we are using codeigniter. where in the code can we put `$redis = new Predis\Client();` so that both functions can use it?

Comment: If $redis a local variable in both functions, this shouldn't be a problem. If it is a global, just use $redis2 or something.

Comment: if we use `$redis = new Predis\Client();` in both functions, would it instantiate two different new Redis clients?

Comment: @baileyJchoi As long as $redis is a local variable in each function, yes.  But each instance will go away as soon as the function is exited. That is, unless you're doing some sort of multithreaded processing, you'll only end up with one instance at a time.  It'd be better to instantiate $redis and $redis2 in the global scope and then pass them to the two functions as arguments. That way the connections will persist after the functions exit.

Comment: You could edit your previous answer instead of deleting it and publishing another one ;D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Fair point. :) By way of explanation but not excuse, I'm on vacation and limited to an iPhone, which makes editing very difficult!